# Posting data using VueJs and Laravel 5

Tags: post, laravel-5, vue.js

I am trying to do the most simple post using Vuejs and laravel but I keep getting an "error 500" along with a strange "Uncaught (in promise)" error when I look it up in chrome dev tools, so heres the code.

**HTML**

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="token" id="token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
    <title>Guestbook</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body>

<div id="chatbox">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <form method="POST" v-on:submit="sendMessage">
                <h1 v-if="nameIsSet">@{{ userInfo.name }}</h1>
                <input type="text" placeholder="Name" v-model="userInfo.name" v-if="! nameIsSet"><button v-if="! nameIsSet" class="btn btn-info" v-on:click="setName">Set Name</button>
                <br>
                <input type="text" placeholder="Message" v-if="nameIsSet" v-model="userInfo.message"><button v-if="nameIsSet">Send Message</button>
                {{ csrf_field() }}
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/1.0.10/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/view-resource.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/guestbook.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**The VueJs Script**

```
Vue.http.headers.common['X-CSRF-TOKEN'] = document.querySelector('#token').getAttribute('value');

new Vue({
    el: '#chatbox',
    data:{
        userInfo:{
            name: '',
            message: ''
        },
        nameIsSet: false
    },
    methods:{
        setName: function(){
            this.nameIsSet = true;
        },
        sendMessage: function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            console.log(userInfo);
            var userInfo = this.userInfo;
            this.$http.post('api/messages', userInfo);
        }
    }
})
```

**The Laravel 5 Routes**

```
Route::get('/', function(){
    return view('guestbook');
});

//API

Route::get('api/messages', function(){
    return App\Message::all();
});

Route::post('api/messages', function(){
    App\Message::create(Request::all());
});
```

As described above it does not work, i'm not sure what the server side error is here anyone gots any ideas ^^?

Comment: If you are in a development environment, turn on debugging mode (see APP_DEBUG in your .env file); this will cause Laravel to display the full error message in the response. Alternately, look at storage/logs/laravel.log for the error message.

Comment: @GeorgeCummins, its in debugging mode by default so its on now, and also the laravel log has the error: [2015-12-01 13:41:03] local.ERROR: exception 'Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\MassAssignmentException' with message 'name' in F:\projects\laravel\vue\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model.php:424

Comment: you're trying to modify a property in `App\Message` that's marked as `guarded`: http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent#mass-assignment  Check the `fillable ` array in `App\Message` to only allow mass assignment in the properties you need it

Comment: wow so i spelt fillable wrong.. i spelt fillabe instead of fillable -_- thanks for telling me or i would have never found that mistake!

Comment: Please show the App\Message Model code

Comment: @Douglas.Sesar, The error has been solved it was a spelling mistake in the App\Message Model I originally put "fillabe" instead of "fillable". So laravel basically said that the $fillable value was no set which is wasn't but its all fixed noww ^^

Comment: Glad to hear you have it fixed; maybe you should add an answer to show that this question has been solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was a simple spelling mistake I put `fillabe` instead of `fillable` when setting the parameters for my `App\Message` Model, Because of this it was returning an error saying that i need to set the variable `Fillable`.

hope this helps anyone who makes a spelling error in a similar place!